# Access token for Sharepoint for Graph API does not work to read the file contents

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token

I am using Access token to browse my files on sharepoint. However, I thought I would be able to read the contents of the files too using that but I land up in below error. Does anyone know how do I resolve this?

> {"error_description":"Exception of type >'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was
> thrown."}

```
# Define imports
import requests
import pathlib

# Copy access_token and specify the MS Graph API endpoint you want to call, e.g. 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' to get all groups in your organization
#access_token = '{ACCESS TOKEN YOU ACQUIRED PREVIOUSLY}'

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/..../search(q='593218')/"
headers = {
  'Authorization': token_result['access_token']
}

consentfilecount=0
clientreportcount = 0
graphlinkcount = 0

while True:
    
    try:
      graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
      graph_result.raise_for_status()
    except:
      token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    
    headers = {
      'Authorization': token_result['access_token']
    }
    

    if ('value' in graph_result.json()):
      for list in graph_result.json()['value']:
        for ele in finalReportNames:
          if ele.lower() in list["name"].lower():
            clientreportcount +=1

#below does not work
                response = requests.get(list["webUrl"],headers={"Authorization": token_result['access_token']})
                print(response)
                print(list["name"])
                print(list["webUrl"])
                print(pathlib.Path(list["name"]).suffix)
            #print(graph_result.json())
          if('@odata.nextLink' in graph_result.json()):
            url = graph_result.json()['@odata.nextLink']
            graphlinkcount += 1
          else:
            break
    
    print(consentfilecount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ***"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException"*** usually occurs if the access token audience is not matching the request or the audience is not the expected value.

As you are making use of Microsoft Graph API query to access SharePoint files, you have to generate and pass the Microsoft Graph access token.

Add **Microsoft Graph API application permissions** in the Azure AD application:

[image]

Hence modify your code by generating token by using below code snippet:

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests

# Set the values for your application
client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'ClientSecret'
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

# Create a ConfidentialClientApplication object
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id
)

# Acquire a token for the client
token_result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

# Get the access token from the token result
access_token = token_result['access_token']

print(access_token)
```

[image]

Make sure that when you decode the access the token, the **aud** must be  **`https://graph.microsoft.com`**

[image]

If you want to query using SharePoint Rest API query, then generate the token by passing scope as `https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/.default`

**To search files,** refer [Use the Microsoft Search API to search OneDrive and SharePoint content - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files)

**To get the file content**, refer [Download a file - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)